# How to show JSON data in jsGrid through PHP file as throughput?

Tags: php, sql-server, jsgrid

This is my first question ever here on SO. So I really hope its clear what I'm asking. If not, please feedback on it.

I'm trying to show the data from a mssql server based database into a JSGRID. I use PHP for this to fetch the data from MSSQL and convert it to JSON so JSGRID can do something with it. I'm trying and tinckering for hours already so I really need some help with this.

HTML main page with Javascript (cut for readability reasons)

```
$("#grid_table").jsGrid({

        height: "450px",
        width: "1200px",

        inserting: true,
        filtering: true,   
        editing: true,
        sorting: true,
        paging: true,
        autoload: true,
        pageSize: 8,
        pageButtonCount: 5,
        deleteConfirm: "Do you really want to delete the client?",

        controller: { 
                loadData: function(filter){
                return $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "fetch_data.php",
                data: filter,
                //contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',//
                dataType: "json", //
                }).then(function(result) {
                return result.data;
                });
            }, 
        },

        fields: [
            {
                name: "Naam",
                type: "text",
                width: 150,
                validate: "required"
            },
            {
                name: "Rol_Id",
                type: "text", 
                items: 
                valueField: "rolnummer",
                textField: "Name",
                width: "auto"
            },  
            {
                name: "Merk_ID", 
                type: "text", 
                width: 100
            }, 
            {
                name: "Email_Adres",
                type: "text",
                width: 300
            },
            {
                name: "Afdeling",
                type: "text",
                width: "auto"
            },  
            {
                type: "control",
                width: "auto"
            }
        ]

});
});
```

fetch_data.php File here:

```
    <?php

$serverName = "hfdwsql01"; 
$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"flexpool_test", "UID"=>"flexpool", "PWD"=>"stPQT%u_8P'd,=&5"); 
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established<br />";
}else{
     echo "No Connection<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

//Script to show data in browser 

$sql = "SELECT Naam, Rol_Id, Merk_ID, Email_Adres, Afdeling FROM Personeel";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
     echo $row['Naam']." , ".$row['Rol_Id']." , ".$row['Merk_ID']." , ".$row['Email_Adres']." , ".$row['Afdeling']."<br />";
}

sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);

//Script for ajax  

$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

if($method == 'GET')
{
    $data = array(
        ":Naam"         => "%" . $_GET['Naam'] . "%", 
        ":Rol_Id"       => "%" . $_GET['Rol_Id'] . "%", 
        ":Merk_ID"      => "%" . $_GET['Merk_ID'] . "%", 
        ":Email_Adres"  => "%" . $_GET['Email_Adres'] . "%", 
        ":Afdeling"     => "%" . $_GET['Afdeling'] . "%" 
    );

    $query = "SELECT * FROM Personeel WHERE Naam LIKE :Naam AND Rol_Id LIKE :Rol_Id AND Merk_ID LIKE :Merk_ID AND Email_Adres LIKE :Email_Adres AND Afdeling LIKE :Afdeling ORDER BY Naam DESC";

    $statement = $conn->prepare($query); 
    $statement->execute($data);
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();

    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        $output[] = array(
                "Naam"          =>  $row['Naam'],
                "Rol_Id"        =>  $row['Rol_Id'],
                "Merk_ID"       =>  $row['Merk_ID'],
                "Email_Adres"   =>  $row['Email_Adres'],
                "Afdeling"      =>  $row['Afdeling'] 
        );
    }

    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    echo json_encode($output);  
}


?>
```

Comment: Hi, please tell us what the problem is that you are trying to solve.

Comment: Great question. So I'm trying to see through a Chrome console if the json is created correctly by the php-file. As a test. Because the jsGrid is not showing any data right now. the jsGrid is showing "Not found". So I'm trying to figure out if my php-file is not containing the right code or controller function incorrectly written.

Comment: Ok, so runh your PHP script raw from the address bar. EG `localhost/fetch_data.php?naam=xxx&Rol_Id=.............` and you should see the resulting JSON displayed on the browser

Comment: If I do that, should i just select the entire code? If yes, I tried, and I get a 404 code. But I DO see the data due to the ' echo $row['Naam'] .....'

Comment: if you get 404 then you have used the url. I dont know where that script lives in your folder structure

Comment: Ok. So I used "http://localhost:55821/fetch_data.php?$serverName..." in the browser. But the browser window shows me nothing else but the PHP-code itself. (this is unlike when I use the url, then it just shows me the 'echo' ofcourse'.)